# Unity CompilationPipeline.GetAssemblyNameFromScriptPath can not get package script's assembly name

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm using `CompilationPipeline.GetAssemblyNameFromScriptPath()` to get a script's assembly name by its path. It works well on asset script but I can't get package script's assembly name.

I've checked the source code of the function and I found it will return `null` if script does not belong to custom assemblies or script's path is not asset path. I also found Monoscript Inspector can show package script's assembly name by using the same function. It is weird that Unity can do it while I can't. I wonder is there anything I missed.

Answer (score 0):

All right,I've found the reason that unity will process package script's path by remove the version of pakcage name.
For example,if your package script's path is "Packages\com.unity.render-pipelines.core@7.3.1\Runtime\Textures\RTHandle.cs",the processed path will be "Packages\com.unity.render-pipelines.core\Runtime\Textures\RTHandle.cs".You should use processed path instead of origin path.